# Why does the Javascript function return right away even with await?

Tags: javascript

I'm newer to JavaScript and struggling to understand why this function just returns right away, even though I added an await. The code below is the minimal example to replicate what I am attempting to do. When I call `add_user()` from `add()`, `id` is `undefined` because `add_user()` is returning right away instead of waiting for completion of the query. I added the console log to verify that `row.id` is the value I expected (i.e. 1).

```
'use strict';

import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
import { open } from 'sqlite';

async function add_user(value) {
   await (async () => {
      const db = await open({
         filename: dbFile,
         driver: sqlite3.Database
      })

      const row = await db.get(`SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name LIKE "${value}"`)
      console.log(row.id)
      return row.id
   })()
}

async function add(req, res) {
    var id = await add_value(req.body.value)
    console.log(id)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? What does "right away" mean? Did you somehow expect the code to run for a couple of seconds? Have you tried adding a sleep into the `add_user` to see that it does *not* return "right away"?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the `await (async () => {` at the beginning of your function? IIFE doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: If `add` is being called from a non-asynchronous context (it's not being awaited), then the function will not run asynchronously and your code will log a promise instead of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the code *is* running asynchronously as desired - it's just that you aren't returning anything from `add_user`. For a smaller example:

```
async function someFn() {
  await somePromise;
}
```

Above, `someFn` will always return a Promise that resolves to `undefined`, because nothing was returned from `someFn`. You're running into the same issue.

Use instead

```
async function add_user(value) {
   const db = await open({
       filename: dbFile,
      driver: sqlite3.Database
   })
   const row = await db.get(`SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name LIKE "${value}"`)
   console.log(row.id)
   return row.id
}
```